# Calculate the image of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently learning how to calculate the image of a matrix.

I used this online resource while learning: https://www.mathebibel.de/bild-einer-matrix

The site provides 3 methods of calculating the image of a matrix, but I noticed that the solutions differ from each other from method to method... is that right?

for example let matrix `A` be defined as follows:

`1 3 2
 2 4 4
 3 5 6`

**if I used the third method that is listed by the site I would:**

1.Use the Gauß Algorithm to get a zero triangle at the bottom. So A becomes:

`**1**  3  2
 0 **-2**  0
 0  0  0`

2.The column index of the first non zero value in each row equals to an image index in the original matrix `A`:

`img = {{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}}`

which would be our solution. But if used the same matrix `A`for another method, we would get a different solution.

**Using the first method on the site that I linked:**

1.transpose the matrix `A`:

`1 2 3
 3 4 5
 2 4 6`

2.Use Gauß:

`1  2  3
 0 -2 -4
 0  0  0`

3.transpose again:

`1  0 0
 2 -2 0
 3 -4 0`

4.every column that doesn't only contain zeroes is part of our image:

`img = {{1,2,3}, {0,-2,-4}}`

as you can see both solutions `img` differ from each other. are both correct?

Comment: You are confusing the basis of a subspace with the subspace itself. See if the two sets of vectors obtained with the different methods span the same space.

Comment: @amd I am not that good at math, so I am not quite sure if I know what you mean. I plotted both vectors in a graph and they are not linear...? which would mean that {1,2,3}, {0,-2,-4} and {3,4,5} are correct solutions...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

\begin{align}
V_1 &= \operatorname{span} \{ (1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5) \},\\
V_2 &= \operatorname{span} \{ (1, 2, 3), (0, -2, -4) \}. \end{align}

Since

$$(3, 4, 5) = 3 \cdot (1, 2, 3) + (0, -2, -4), $$

it follows that $V_1 \subseteq V_2$ and

$$(0, -2, -4) = (3, 4, 5) - 3 \cdot (1, 2, 3)$$

implies that we have $V_2 \subseteq V_1$, therefore $V_1 = V_2$. The solutions are the same.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. thanks